# Inheritance - Can't access base class data member in derived class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

One doubt in inheritance, I have two class named **A** and **B**.
**A** is **Base Class** and **B** is **Derived Class**.
B Class inheriting two data members and two member functions of A Class.

> In derived class, accessing the **static data member** is Working but
>   accessing the **non static data member** gives error. This same case is
>   also for Member Functions. I can't access non static member function.

If i access either static or non static **variable | function** inside any of derived class function it working fine.

Why i can't access directly in a class. Why its not showing error when i access inside of any derived class function. Any one please clarify my doubts.

[image: reference Image]

```
 class A
{
    protected string msg1;
    protected static string msg2;

    protected  string alert1() {
        return "Welcome";
    }
    protected static string alert2()
    {
        return "Welcome All";
    }
}
class B : A {

    string copyMsg1 = msg1;
    string copyMsg2 = msg2;

    string getMsg1 = alert1();
    string getMsg2 = alert2();

    void display() {
        msg1 = "";
        msg2 = "";
        alert2();           
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code instead of its picture. So we can copy that.

Comment: @Farzin Kanzi Code added in my question please check it

Comment: Well, `alert` is an instance method. You can't access it without having an instance of the class first.

Comment: You can not access `this` in fields initializers. No matter if it [same class member](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27491406) or base class member.

Comment: @CKing, I have accessed the `alert` function of base class without creating instance in derived class function `display`. please refer it

Comment: @MuthuramanSundararaj: CKing's comment is wrong. PetSerAl's comment is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is illegal:

```
string getMsg1 = alert1();
```

Because it is equivalent to

```
string getMsg1 = this.alert1();
```

and accessing `this` in a field initializer is illegal. Why? Because field initializers run *before* either the derived class constructor or the base class constructor, and therefore you could be calling a method that *depends on the constructor having already run*.

The correct solution is to put your initializations into the constructor:

```
class B : A {
  string copyMsg1;
  string copyMsg2; 
  string getMsg1;
  string getMsg2;

  public B() 
  {
    this.copyMsg1 = this.msg1;
    this.copyMsg2 = A.msg2; 
    this.getMsg1 = this.alert1();
    this.getMsg2 = A.alert2();
  }
```

The body of the constructor runs *after* the field initializers of the derived class, the field initializers of the base class, and the constructor body of the base class. The derived constructor body runs *last*, and therefore you know that all the stuff it accesses has already been created.

While we're at it: note that methods in C# traditionally begin with a capital letter.

Also, there is not really a good reason shown in this code to do the copying at all. You already have access to the base class members from the derived class, so why are you copying them into the derived class?

Comment: you explained **well**,  the program has no logic, i just created for explaining my question

Answer (score 1):

> If i access either static or non static variable | function inside any of derived class function it working fine.
>
> Why i can't access directly in a class. Why its not showing error when i access inside of any derived class function. Any one please clarify my doubts.

In other words you question is: Why can I access the static fields at the class level (outside of any methods or properties) but not instance fields.

Static fields are per class. You do not need an instance of the class but you need the class to be available. Therefore, if the class is available, then you can access it.

Now let's go to *non-static* fields. Here is your class, please note the numbers in comments:

```
class B : A {

    string copyMsg1 = msg1; <-- 1. assign non-static to non static 
    string copyMsg2 = msg2; <-- 2. assign static to non static

    string getMsg1 = alert1(); <-- 3. non static calling non-static
    string getMsg2 = alert2(); <-- 4. non static calling static

    void display() {
        msg1 = "";
        msg2 = "";
        alert2();           
    }
}
```

1. This is NOT allowed because they are both instance fields (non-static), and there is no guarantee that there will be an instance of `A` available at this point.
2. This is allowed because instance fields can access static fields. But not the other way around because an instance may not be avaialbe. Instance fields, methods, and properties can access both static and non static.
3. This is NOT allowed because of item 1 above.
4. This is allowed because of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Call the non-static method inside a setter method :

```
class A
   {
       protected string alert()
       {
           return "me";
       }
   }

    class B :A
    {
        private string s;

        private void setS()
        {
            s = alert();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its a good answer. You can use inherited objects in the methods of child class.

Comment: @AliEzzatOdeh, okay, Why i cant access it directly.

Comment: You can't call a non-static method directly without calling it from an instance(object) because the non-static method is per instance, but you can call it from an implementation of a method, the setter here,which won't be called unless an object is created. 
On the other hand the static method is shared for all objects so it can be called without creating an object (called from the class directly).