# Order of Instantiation

Tags: c#

A question I'm having trouble finding the answer to: When my class is instantiated, in what order are it's members instantiated.

For example, can I set a member to the value of a member lower in the declaration order? (See code example.)

```
// Can I do the following:

class foo
{
    int A = B;
    int B = 12;
}

// And this, for class types:

class bar
{
    foo X = Y;
    foo Y = new foo();
}
```

Comment: You can not reference `this` in field initializers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491406/understanding-c-sharp-field-initialization-requirements

Comment: Q: What happened when you tried to compile?  And how could assigning from a variable you haven't declared yet *POSSIBLY* be a good thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "will my compiler compile this code?" is a question best answered by your compiler.

Comment: @KevinPaulTracy This question is getting downvoted and is well on its way to being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The order of field instantiation does not matter in this case. What matters is that **you cannot use non-static field, method or property in the field initializer**. So, it doesn't matter if you do:

```cs
class Foo
{
    int A = B;
    int B = 12;
}
```

or the opposite order

```cs
class Foo
{
    int B = 12;
    int A = B;
}
```

Your code will not compile anyway. You will get `A field initialize cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Foo.B'` error.

So, you shouldn't worry about the order because this situation can never occur.

Comment: The error I get is: Cannot use local variable 'B' before it is declared. When I reverse the order it works fine.

Comment: @KevinPaulTracy That error is because you are trying to access an __still__ not existen member of the class. To achieve what you are looking for... you will need to do that in the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't do it.

You will get the following compilation error :

*Error  CS0236  **A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property** 'Program.foo.A'  Test    C:\Users\sebas\source\repos\Test\Test\Program.cs    14  Active*

I you extend the question to static field, they are executed from the first to the latest one.

It can easily be tested with the following code :

```
    class foo
    {
        public static int A = foo.B;
        public static int B = 3;
        public static int C = foo.B;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.A);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.B);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.C);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The result will be :

```
0
3
3
```

Anyway. Even if it was working, I would suggest that you just use a constructor. You will gain in maintainability.

Comment: The error I get is: Cannot use local variable 'B' before it is declared. When I reverse the order it works fine.

Comment: @KevinPaulTracy Please share the full, complete, exact code, and the exact name and exact version of the compiler, where you got that error. [Here's what a conformant C# compiler says about it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x21KZs).

Answer (score 1):

Despite the bad example, it's worth understanding how initialization actually works. The draft C# 6.0 Spec has this to say about it:

> The default value initialization described in Field initialization occurs for all fields, including fields that have variable initializers. Thus, when a class is initialized, all static fields in that class are first initialized to their default values, and then the static field initializers are executed in textual order. Likewise, when an instance of a class is created, all instance fields in that instance are first initialized to their default values, and then the instance field initializers are executed in textual order.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#field-initialization