# Using a method made in a parent class in a child class c#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
    class ClassOne 
{
    Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
    public Stack<int> MakeStack()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            
            s.Push(i);
        }
        return s;
    }

}


class ClassTwo:ClassOne
{
    Stack<int> st = MakeStack();
    int[] array = new int[2];
    private int[] GetFirstTwo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            array[i] = st.Pop();
        }
        
        return array;
    }

}
```

but when I am trying to use MakeStack in the child class it gives the error "A field initalizer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ClassOne.MakeStack'.

I know one fix would be to do everything inside the parent class and make it abstract for when I need to override things inside different child classes, but was hoping there is a way to do what I need without all that as I couldnt find anything helpful when looking into it.

Comment: You refer to MakeDeck. We don’t see that code.

Comment: MakeDeck refers to my actual code, not this dummy piece I wrote. Have edited it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the constructor:

```
class ClassTwo : ClassOne
{
    Stack<int> st;
    
    ClassTwo()
    {
        st = MakeStack();
    }
    // ...
}
```

For the *why* look for example here: [Understanding C# field initialization requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491406/understanding-c-sharp-field-initialization-requirements)